# Optimizer Occasionally chooses a bad plan - how to tune query to ensure it is consistent

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2016, execution-plan, performance-tuning

I have a query in my environment which occasionally gets a "bad" plan and takes a long time to run.
We can see from the query store output below that the query normally uses plan `25493651` but occasionally uses plan `25267081` which results in a significantly worse runtime.

[image]

I know I can force the "good" plan in query store but this creates a bit of technical debt in that this may not be an efficient plan in future.

I need to try and fix this so that the query runtime is consistent. The problem I have is that I cannot see the actual plan in Query store for the "bad" plan so can't really see where it is going wrong, I am also not on SQL Server 2019 so can't make use of the new "see last actual plan" plan cache feature

My thoughts are that this is likely to be an estimation issue and the code has a number of code "smells" such as non sargable predicates and implicit conversions which may support this theory.

I thought that if I can significantly improve the performance of the query, that should be enough for the optimizer to choose the plan for that improved query over the previous "good" and "bad" plans. Whilst I have had some success in reducing the reads on the query from 255,078 to 239,285 by creating an index, I don't think this would be significant enough to be confident that the cost of the optimized query is significantly better than the previous plans?

The query runs once nightly as a part of a data warehouse build

The anonymized code is below, it cannot really be changed to fix the issue as it is vendor code so options are limited, however, I could suggest a code change if I had some evidence that would fix the issue

the anonymized "good" and "bad" plans are below, though as they are taken from query store, they are only estimates

[Good](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SJaNS-aAc)

[Bad](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SyvSI-p09)

```
INSERT INTO [Object6]
(
       Column1, 
       Column2, 
       Column3, 
       Column4, 
       Column5, 
       Column6, 
       Column7, 
       Column8
)
SELECT    CAST([ALIAS].[Column8] + ' literaltext' AS VARCHAR(255)), 
          CAST('literaltext' AS VARCHAR(255)), 
          MAX(ISNULL([Object2].Column21, Object2.Column17)), 
          CAST('Y' AS CHAR(1)), 
          [Object1].Column13, 
          [Object1].Column6, 
          [ALIAS].[Column8], 
          CAST(SUM(CAST(1 AS INT)) AS INT)
FROM      [Object2]
          INNER JOIN [Object4]
              ON Object2.Column12 = Object4.Column8
                 AND 'literaltext' = Object4.LookupType
                 AND 'literaltext' = Object4.Column19
          INNER JOIN [Object3]
               ON Object2.Column16 = Object3.Column1
          INNER JOIN [Object1]
               ON Object3.Column2 = Object1.Column6
                 AND Object2.Column17 >= Object1.Column5
                 AND Object1.Column4 IS NULL
          INNER JOIN [Object5] AS ALIAS
               ON 'literaltext' = ALIAS.Column11
          LEFT JOIN [Object5]
               ON Object5.Column11 = 'literaltext'
          LEFT JOIN [Object7]
               ON [Object7].Column10 = CAST([ALIAS].Column8 + ' literaltext' AS VARCHAR(255))
                  AND [Object7].Column3 = ISNULL([Object2].Column21, Object2.Column17)
                  AND [Object7].Column5 = [Object1].Column13
                  AND [Object7].Column6 = [Object1].Column6
                  AND [Object7].[Column1] = 'literaltext'
 WHERE(ISNULL(Object5.Column8, 'Y') = 'Y')
       AND ([Object7].Column10 IS NULL
       AND CAST([ALIAS].[Column8] + 'literaltext' AS VARCHAR(255)) IS NOT NULL
       AND [Object7].Column3 IS NULL
       AND ISNULL([Object2].Column21, Object2.Column17) IS NOT NULL
       AND [Object7].Column5 IS NULL
       AND [Object1].Column13 IS NOT NULL
       AND [Object7].Column6 IS NULL
       AND [Object1].Column6 IS NOT NULL)
 GROUP BY CAST([ALIAS].[Column8] + ' literaltext' AS VARCHAR(255)), 
          [Object1].Column13, 
          [Object1].Column6, 
          [ALIAS].[Column8]
 HAVING CAST(SUM(CAST(1 AS INT)) AS INT) >= ALIAS.Column8;
```

How do I understand what is causing the estimator to choose the "bad" plan on occasion and how might I try to rectify this?

Comment: Perhaps columnstore (cci or ncci)?

Comment: `HAVING CAST(SUM(CAST(1 AS INT)) AS INT) >= ALIAS.Column8` has to be one of the weirdest predicates I've ever seen. Either way, if you cannot modify the query there isn't a huge amount you can do outside of indexing, none of which you have shown.

Comment: Here's my opinion: "The query runs once nightly as a part of a data warehouse build" is not compatible with "this creates a bit of technical debt in that this may not be an efficient plan in future." Force the good plan. That's your answer.

Comment: @Charlieface, besides the having the following is also weird, unless the code is paid per symbol: 
WHERE
 (ISNULL(Object5.Column8, 'Y') = 'Y')
 AND ([Object7].Column10 IS NULL
 AND CAST([ALIAS].[Column8] + 'literaltext' AS VARCHAR(255)) IS NOT NULL

Comment: Just an FYI, the clustered index scan on `Object2.Index7` has an obscene cardinality estimate. I know this is only the estimated plan, but that may be a clue too. It looks like there's an index suggestion too. You may want to play around with that. I think there's more relevant info in your plan's XML too, but I'm having a hard time going through it on my phone. Best of luck!

Comment: @J.D we added one of the indexes a few weeks back and it has settled down it seems. We never got to the bottom of what it was that caused the plan to go "bad" every now and then